# S3 Multipart Upload: how can I cancel one?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to cancel an in-progress download that was initiated with

```
fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(/*...*/);
var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest() /* config parameters... */
fileTransferUtility.BeginUpload(uploadRequest, new AsyncCallback(uploadComplete), file);
```

I have searched SO and documentation, but I can't find a way...

Rationale: the user can pick a file to upload, and may choose a very large file, say 1GB. I need to be able to cancel this.

In the worst case, I could just try to kill the thread entirely, or shut down the upload in an unclean way, but how???

Thanks!

Comment: Try this ans-w for you problem? [http://serverfault.com/questions/246419/cannot-upload-files-bigger-than-8gb-to-amazon-s3-by-multi-part-upload-due-to-bro](http://serverfault.com/questions/246419/cannot-upload-files-bigger-than-8gb-to-amazon-s3-by-multi-part-upload-due-to-bro)  and [https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=123033](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=123033)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I received an [official answer from Amazon](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=450230#450230) on this. Here is their reply:

```
var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(/* */);
var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();

Thread thread = new Thread(() => fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest));
Thread.Sleep(5000); // If not done in 5 seconds abort
if(thread.IsAlive)
    thread.Abort();
```

Instead of using `BeginUpload`/`EndUpload` calls, you need to use a `Upload` call wrapped in a Thread, and heep the reference to this thread.

If the user needs to cancel, call `Abort()` on the thread, which will cancel the upload. Of course, you need to clean partially uploaded files (they bill for them!).

As I suspected: very simple and intuitive, but not so easy to find :)

Comment: I needed to add a call to `thread.Start()` before this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like :

```
s3Client.AbortMultipartUpload(new AbortMultipartUploadRequest()
  .WithBucketName(bucketName)
  .WithKey(key)
  .WithUploadId(Response.UploadId));
}
```

see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/html/M_Amazon_S3_AmazonS3_AbortMultipartUpload.htm

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this will not stop the currently uploading thread. Moreover, the TransferUtility will do a multipart upload only if it exceeds a certain size, otherwise will do a standard upload, which is unaffected by this call.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping the Upload into a thread works, but, at least to me, it takes quite a long time, if the file is big to Abort the thread. Anyone sees this too?