# Cancel a file upload using .Net client for Amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I'm writing an app that allows users to browse and upload large files to Amazon S3 via a web application.  I'm using the Amazon AWS library for .Net.  However because the files are large I want to provide a 'Cancel' option on the website.  I can't see anything in the API as to how to cancel a file that's uploading using S3.  Does anyone know how to cancel file uploads?

Thanks.

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485629/s3-multipart-upload-how-can-i-cancel-one

Comment: also refer this http://netpalantir.it/news/index/how-to-cancel-an-in-progress-multipart-upload-using-amazon-s3-in-c-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it just by using `Thread.Abort()`